# Sliding the last tab of HorizontalPager causes distortion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Sliding the last HorizontalPager tab on Jetpack Compose causes the view to bounce but it won't come back to it's original form.

Expected:
[image]

Result after sliding multiple times:
[image]

Have anyone experienced this before? What are the possible solutions?

Latest library versions for this day.

```
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00')


composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
}
```

Comment: can you please provide your compose code its hard to know what is actually causing the issue